# Why is it necessary in the Merge-Sort algorithm to divide the array into two before sorting it?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, merge

This might be a stupid question, but I was wondering why it is necessary for the merge sort algorithm to divide the list into two and mergesort each partition before merging all of these partitions into a sorted list as this animation shows:

http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~courses/coe428/sorting/mergesort.html

It seems that near the end of the mergesort algorithm when it reaches phase where it merges the two large arrays together, why not just do that in the first place? I don't see why it is necessary to mergesort every part of the array while it seems that the algorithm could just divide the entire list into two and merge them together in a sorted array on the first step.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The easiest way to understand this is to code a merge of two sorted arrays as an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see why it is necessary to mergesort every part of the array while it seems that the algorithm could just divide the entire list into two and merge them together in a sorted array on the first step.

You seem to be missing the fact that the merge only works if the parts being merged are already in sorted order. If you just try to split the input into two halves and merge them without recursively sorting them, the merge won't work and the output won't actually be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that variations of bottom up merge sort are what are actually used in most libraries, such as std::stable_sort. Rather than recursively dividing lists and sub-lists into two parts until a size of 1 is reached, a bottom up merge sort skips the unneeded recursion and simply treats a list of n elements as n lists with 1 element each, and begins merging pairs of sub-lists, increasing the sorted run size on each pass until the entire list is sorted.

In either case of top down or bottom up (non hybrid) merge sort, no merging takes place until run sizes of 1 are produced, since a run of size 1 can be considered to be sorted. After that, runs of size 1 are merged to form runs of size 2, then those runs merged to form runs of size 4 and so on, until a single run with the same size as the original list is produced.

As a variation, a hybrid merge sort may only reduce sub-list size to some small amount, like 32 elements, then use something like insertion sort on the 32 element sub-lists, before starting the merge process.

The wiki article on merge sort has a simplified example of bottom up merge sort:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation

Answer (score 0):

The merge only works with *sorted* lists. Thus you divide until you get one or two elements, which can be trivially sorted either by leaving it alone or with a swap. Then you do the merging which takes elements in sequence from one or the other list. That's why both lists have to be sorted and also why the result is sorted.